# How can I simulate/emulate a gamepad in xCode?

Tags: xcode, bluetooth, simulate, emulation, gamepad

**Background:**
I have a Bluetooth gamepad which I can discover and connect to through xCode. I can communicate with it through the Control and Interrupt channel and thus I can find out which buttons on the Gamepad are being pressed. I can then map this to a keyboard button.

However, most recent games look for an actual gamepad or joystick to enable multiplayer functions as only one player is allowed to play on the keyboard and mouse. Since my gamepad currently only simulates the keyboard buttons the game does not recognize a gamepad and thus will not unlock the multiplayer mode.

**Question:**
I have no idea where to look for, but is there a way I can simulate a gamepad so the MAC actually recognizes it as a joystick/gamepad and I can map the buttons accordingly?

I am coding in xCode 4.6.1 for a Mac OSX "Mountain Lion" APP.